# Replicate/Mirror SQL Server schema to slave databases

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, schema, mirroring

I have a empty database called `MASTERDB` and around 10, or more, slave databases that are copies of the `MASTERDB` database.

`MASTERDB` will be always empty, as I only need the schema. No data is going to be replicated/mirrored.

The scenario:

- I create a new table on MASTERDB and I want that table to be created on those 10 tables automatically
- If I change a field on MASTERDB, replicate the changes for all the other databases

I have looked at [Mirroring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188712.aspx) and [Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152562.aspx), but I could not determine if these will do what I want.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What would happen if one of the changes to MASTERDB worked in only 9 of the 10 databases? (lets say a user process blocked the update)  I agree with Remus below.  This is a change control problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither mirroring nor replicaiton are appropiate here. Mirroring creates identical physical copies of the database. Replication is good at replicating data, but falls short exactly at replicating schema changes, so you would use the very wrong tool for the job.

What you describe is a a problem of change control, not replicaiton. You should approach it as such. My favourite approach is described in [Version Control and your Database](http://rusanu.com/2009/05/15/version-control-and-your-database/). Brent Ozar PLF's last video also addresses the same problem: [Coping with Change Control Video](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/12/coping-change-control-video/).

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to check out the links and let you know.